# Resource allocation for QoS Burstable pods in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

If `limit` resources are greater than `request` resources, K8 will assign pod to [QoS Burstable](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/quality-service-pod/#create-a-pod-that-gets-assigned-a-qos-class-of-burstable)

Sample configuration:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: test-metadata
  namespace: demo
spec:
  containers:
  - name: test1
    image: nginx
    resources:
      limits:
        memory: "14Gi"
      requests:
        memory: "4Gi"
```

- Will Kubernetes **always** assign this pod on an instance that will have 14GB memory?
- Will Kubernetes **always** reserve 14 GB memory for this pod? If yes, then how is it different than `QoS Guaranteed` class?

I don't want to use `QoS Guaranteed` as the workload can vary.

Comment: Can requests be actually larger than limits? I'm sure API server wouldn't accept it.

Comment: What version of k8s do you use? When you apply this manifest, server should return an error similar to `spec.containers[0].resources.requests: Invalid value: "14Gi": must be less than or equal to memory limit`

Comment: @zerkms my bad it's the other way around.

Comment: Then answers to your both questions is "no". It will place it on a node with at least 4Gi memory (counted only by `available - total requested`) and would let the process consume as much as 14Gb (without guaranteeing they ever will be available).

Comment: @zerkms So, it could be possible that the pod will start on a node (e.g `m5.large` ) with 8 GB RAM (which is greater than the `request` resources) and the pod will die with OOM before reaching 14GB.

Comment: Correct ...........

Comment: @Dev Not necessary, there can be no OOMs. That depends on [eviction policies](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/out-of-resource/). If you set some eviction threshold, when this threshold will be met, pod will be evicted before it throws OOM and scheduler gonna try to place it at more appropriate node.

Comment: @Dev do these comments answer you question?

Comment: @PiotrMalec partly yes. Looks like I need to read more about Kubernetes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Memory limits are not taken into consideration when scheduling pods.

*Will Kubernetes always assign this pod on an instance that will have 14GB memory?*

By default, this pod will be assigned to any node that meets the request for 4GB memory.

On the node side, any pod that uses more than its requested resources is subject to eviction when the node runs out of resources. In other words, Kubernetes never provides any guarantees of availability of resources beyond a Pod's requests.

Using a memory limit that exceeds the node's total memory will never be reached.

*Will Kubernetes always reserve 14 GB memory for this pod? If yes, then how is it different than QoS Guaranteed class?*

No, by default kubernetes will reserve the least amount of memory needed which would be 4GB as request.

Scheduler also takes into consideration [scheduler configuration](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/scheduling/config/) and [scheduler policies](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/scheduling/policies/):

> Scheduler configuration allows to customize the behavior of the `kube-scheduler` by writing a configuration file and passing its path as a command line argument.

> A scheduling Policy can be used to specify the *predicates* and *priorities* that the [kube-scheduler](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kube-scheduler/) runs to [filter and score nodes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/kube-scheduler/#kube-scheduler-implementation), respectively.

Answer (score 1):

By default Kubernetes takes only resource requests into account when trying to schedule the pods. This means that your pod will only be scheduled to some node which has at least so much resources available as requested by the pod.

To be even more precise the pod is going to be scheduled to one of the nodes such that sum of the resources requested by all the pods ( including the pod it is trying to schedule ) does not exceed the nodes allocatable resources. Here the operative words are **allocatable resources**.

Allocatable resources are those resources, which are available in excess of resources necesarry to operate system pods. How much of the hardware resources are reserved for system processes is configurable property of Kubernetes and is better described in [their documentation of node allocatable resources](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/reserve-compute-resources/#node-allocatable)

Comment: Is there any better way to allocate dynamic resources?

Comment: If you leave out the requests then the pods can be scheduled on any node. In thic case it is advisable to at least set the limits. Note that these arecmot quite best practices